# Unable to run script through selenium grid. Got timeout error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-grid

Here is the log for Hub creation
[image]

Here is the log for Node creation
[image]

Here is Grid console output

[image]

Driver folder
[image]

This is the Python Script I wrote

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class SearchProducts(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platform'] = 'WINDOWS'
        desired_caps['browserName'] = 'chrome'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://192.168.43.250:4444/wd/hub', desired_caps)
        self.driver.get('http://demo.magentocommerce.com/')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def testSearchByCategory(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_icon = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Search')]/preceding::span/div")
        self.search_icon.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inputWrapper']//input[@id='edit-keys']")
        self.search_field.click()
        self.search_field.clear()
        # enter search keyword and submit
        self.search_field.send_keys('phones')
        self.search_field.submit()
        time.sleep(5)

    def tearDown(self):
        # close the browser window
        self.driver.quit()
```

When ran script I got below log at Console

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jyothi\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
conn = connection.create_connection(
File "C:\Users\jyothi\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Users\jyothi\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001A30BD477C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 60, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 672, in run
    self._callSetUp()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 630, in _callSetUp
    self.setUp()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\src\test\automation\web\test.py", line 12, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://192.168.43.250:4444/wd/hub', desired_caps)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 79, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 336, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 752, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 752, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 752, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\apautomationpython\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.43.250', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001A30BD477C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Everything seems fine to me but Whats going wrong? How to resolve this error? Please help

Comment: Have you got the right  up?  Console window's suggest you're at 192.168.1.108 but your code is different... If its all on your local machine try localhost?

Comment: oh yes .. I have been using wrong ip address. Thanks! Test ran. But test ran only over chrome not over ie?

Comment: you specify your capabilities as windows and chrome? - thats as expected? :-)

Comment: ohh .. how to define multiple & to run them parallel?

Comment: You need fixtures at the start of the test class to input different parameters, essentially making the 1 test into 2 or more - but I think that's another question mate! :-)  have a Google about running grid on multiple browsers, have a go and if you get stuck come back and post again